# XAMPP in Program Files directory

Tags: xampp

> Important! Because an activated User Account Control (UAC) on your
>   system some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted. With UAC
>   please avoid to intall XAMPP to C:\Program Files (missing write
>   permissions). Or deactivate UAC with msconfig after this setup.

I was searching for any farther information, but nothing found. Does anybody know what exact problems might I have if I would install XAMPP on Program Files with enabled UAC (especially on Windows 8/8.1)?

Answer (score 0):

Apache2, for example needs write access, which wont be granted by Windows for any program trying to write into the program files directory. Obviously for security reasons, otherwise a program could manipulate other programs. 
I don't know exactly, why Apache needs write access, but I think it is because of the log files, which are contained in some sub-directories of the installation